# copy all the packages via gulp using package.json

Tags: npm, gulp

I would like to copy the content of all the npm packages in my npm **package.json** to another directory inside my project. Since npm already knows the client packages and the development packages, I would like to do this without to change the gulp file every time a package is added. I'm not interested to select files inside the packages, just copy all the client packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about using [gulp-npm-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-npm-files)?

```
// Copy dependencies to build/node_modules/ 
gulp.task('copyNpmDependenciesOnly', function() {
  gulp.src(gnf(), {base:'./'}).pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```